# jQuery .each() in a nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My apologies for the long post but I'll give you the full story. I have a page that lists some products and below each has a little jQueryUI calendar to select a delivery date. I won't get into why, but I have to do what I'm doing with client side scripting.

I'm using jQuery to loop through each product name. For each one, it checks an array of keywords and takes action if the product name is found anywhere in the array.

The end action will be using a call to the associated calendar datepicker and apply a minimum and maximum date to it (that's easy).

What I'm having trouble with now is that I've decided to use a nested array for the product names and the dates you're allowed to choose to have those delivered.  So instead of just an array of keywords, I have:

```
var keywordArray = [
    //product name, start date, end date
    ["foo","2/1/2014","2/13/2014"],
    ["bar","2/7/2014","2/12/2014"]
];
```

So "foo" can only be delivered between 2/1 and 2/13.

---

Given this, my inner loop to go through the array needs modified, but I haven't figure out how to do it.  It worked great when the array was just a simple array of keywords, but now I need to test the first element of each array in the array of arrays (what a mouthful).

```
function checkAllowedDates() {
    $("div[id^='delivery_product_name_']").each(function(index) {   //outer loop (each product name)

        str = $("div#delivery_product_name_"+parseInt(index+1)).text(); //gets text inside 'delivery_product_name_1', _2, etc...

        $.each(keywordArray,function(index,value){  //test all array values to see if any are in the product name

            if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) >= 0) {    //contains a keyword
            console.log(str+ " contains the special keyword " + value);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I tried using value[0], no dice. I googled/binged how to use nested arrays, and found some great examples and I could probably do it using a normal for loop, but I really wanted to use jQuery on this.

So short form: how do I use **$.each()** to loop through an array of arrays, and test the 0th index of each inner array (the product name string) to see if it matches the current product name text of my outer loop?

Comment: Off topic of your question, but I would suggest looking into using data- attributes for storing data like "index" instead of parsing the IDs of your elements. That's got a strong "code smell" to me.

Comment: Since "value" is an array, you would need value[0] to get the keyword. You say that you tried the provided code with value[0] instead of value and it didn't work? Note: For efficiency, I'd convert str to lower case outside the loop.

Comment: I ended up getting this to work with value[0], I'm not sure why I was failing at first.

    if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(value[0].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {  //contains a keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you not simply use a data structure that is easier to work with like:

```
var keywordObj = {
    foo: ["2/1/2014","2/13/2014"],
    bar: ["2/7/2014","2/12/2014"]
};
```

This way you have a key against which you can perform a lookup. This prevents you from needing to do a nested loop at all.  You could simply get start/end dates based on your `str` value like this:

```
var startDate = keywordObj[str][0];
var endDate = keywordObj[str][1];
```

You could even have nested object to get specific startDate/endDate properties like

```
var keywordObj = {
    foo: {
        startDate: "2/1/2014",
        endDate: "2/13/2014"
    },
    bar: {
        startDate: "2/7/2014",
        endDate: "2/12/2014"
    }
};
```

And then access like:

```
var selectedItem = keywordObj[str];
console.log(selectedItem.startDate);
console.log(selectedItem.endDate);
```

To summarize, because you are not structuring you data for easy lookup, you are having to do an unnecessary loop to find the data you are looking for in your data structure. This means your operation has operational complexity of O(n) when it could have O(1).  Always think about your data structure and how it needs to be set up to get to the data in best manner.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$.each(arr, function(){
  console.log("outer loop")
  console.log(this)
  $.each(this, function(){
    console.log("inner loop")
    console.log(this)
  })
})
```

And output is like

```
outer loop
[1, 2]
inner loop
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
inner loop
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 2}
outer loop
[3, 4]
inner loop
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 3}
inner loop
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkAllowedDates() {
    $("div[id^='delivery_product_name_']").each(function(index) {   //outer loop (each product name)

        str = $("div#delivery_product_name_"+parseInt(index+1)).text(); //gets text inside 'delivery_product_name_1', _2, etc...

        $.each(keywordArray,function(index,value){  //test all array values to see if any are in the product name

            if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(value[0]) >= 0) {    //contains a keyword
            console.log(str+ " contains the special keyword " + value[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but got this line wrong

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(value[0]) >= 0) {
```

It should actually be the other way around

```
if (value.indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
```

The format is

```
array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])
```

More info and examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)